# Passing array of struct expected unqualified id error

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm getting the error "expected unqualified-id before '[' token on the line where I'm trying to set the RainData[inMonth].rain = inData. I'm not really sure how to pass an array of structs into a function in general, or how to access the elements once they're passed in. You don't have to write my code, but any help and explanation I would appreciate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct RainData
{
    string  name;                          // Name of a month
    double  rain;                          // Rainfall for that month

    RainData(string n ="", double r = 0.0) // Constructor that uses default
    { name = n; rain = r;}                 // values if fewer than 2
};                                         // arguments are passed to it

// Function prototypes
void getData(RainData[], int);

const int NUM_MONTHS = 12;

int main()
{
    RainData month [NUM_MONTHS] = {RainData("January"), RainData("February")... (edited for space);

    getData(month, NUM_MONTHS);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}


void getData(RainData[], int numElts)
{
    // Enter and store the rainfall for each month
    int inMonth;
    double inData;
    cout << "Enter a month number. (ex. 1 = January) ";
    cin >> inMonth;
    cout << "Enter rain data. ";
    cin >> inData;
    RainData[inMonth].rain = inData;
}
```

Comment: Can you try modify the `getData` function header (NOT the prototype) to `void getData(RainData[] data, int numElts)` and change the line that causes the error to `data[inMonth].rain = inData;`?

Comment: You could have used `RainData month[NUM_MONTHS] = { "January", "February", ` etc.

Comment: It'd be a better idea to have the month name not stored in the RainData object, since in the `getData` function you assume the objects are in month order anyway

Comment: M.M what do you mean? So just have the numbers represent the months, or have the user enter the names, something else? I have to output them and sort them at some point. Not really sure how I will do it. I used to know this stuff but it's been years so I'm still trying to relearn functions and basic syntax. The programs organization is suffering though :(.

Answer (score 0):

`RainData` is a type, not a variable, that's why you are getting the error.

You forgot to put a name in your parameter:

```
void getData(RainData someData[], int numElts)
```

and then:

```
someData[inMonth].rain = inData;
```

Comment: hehe, yes, fixed.

Comment: Yeah that did it thanks. I knew that it was a type not a variable but I wasn't sure how to solve it. The name in the parameter makes sense though. I appreciate the help.